# Application of Sperner's Lemma.

Tags: game-theory

The triangle $ABC$ is divided into sub-simplices in a non-trivial way (there exists at least one point on each of the segments $AB$, $AC$, $BC$ other than $A$, $B$ and $C$).

We label the vertices by
numbers in $\{1, 2, 3\}$ according to the following rules:

• $A$ gets $2$ or $3$, $B$ gets $1$ or $3$ and $C$ gets $1$ or $2$.

• Any vertex on $AB$ gets $3$.

• Any vertex on $AC$ gets $2$.

• Any vertex on $BC$ gets $1$.

• Any other vertex gets 1, 2 or 3.

Is it true that there must exists a triangle labeled by 1, 2, 3? Prove or find a counterexample.

I tend to believe that this proposition is true, and should be proved by a reduction to Sperner's Lemma. However - I cannot put my mind into finding a solution.

I would love to see a solution if this is actually true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true.

Pick one on vertex from each of $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$, none of which is equal to $A$, $B$, or $C$. By the given conditions, these have distinct labels. Now apply Sperner's lemma with those as the three outer vertices.

For example, here is a triangulation meeting the given conditions, with one vertex selected on each of the edges (the enlarged ones). Note that a triangulation is a purely combinatorial object; you could just as well view it as a triangulation of the circle. Then to apply Sperner's lemma, all you need is *some* 3 vertices on the circle, of 3 distinct colors, and so that the vertices along the arcs between them only contain the 2 colors of the endpoints.

[image: sperner]

Comment: They don't have to have distinct labels, that's the tricky part.

Comment: I mean to pick one on each of $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$, none of which is equal to $A,B,C$. Then the conditions state that they have distinct labels.

Comment: They don't have to be connected, imagine a triangle split up into billion of subtriangles.

Comment: I don't mean to pick those as the rainbow triangle; I mean to pick them as the outer vertices of the *big* triangle to which you apply sperner's lemma. I updated the answer with a picture